# Set focus to NewItemRow after row inserted from a NewItemRow

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm using the DevExpress XPF `GridControl`'s `NewItemRow` for inserting data to my database.

When I press enter in the last cell it enters the data and returns to the top row of the grid.

What I would like it to do is return to the `NewItemRow` so the user can start inserting the new record without needing to reselect the `NewItemRow` row.

How i could set focus to NewItemRow after row inserted from a NewItemRow?

ps: I'm asking here rather than the DevExpress forums as here gets a much quicker response :)

EDIT:

Here is some code I have tried but it had exactly the same result:

```
void MVVMFriendlyDxgTableView_RowUpdated(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowEventArgs e)
{
  if (RowUpdatedCommand != null)
  {
    if (e.Row != null)
    {
      if (RowUpdatedCommand.CanExecute(e.Row))
      {
        RowUpdatedCommand.Execute(e.Row);
        if (e.RowHandle == GridControl.NewItemRowHandle)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                SelectRow(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle);
            }));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code with people. And try devexpress forums also. They are really quick also.

Comment: What type of code are you currently using..? do you have a query that runs after the Inserted Row what does your SQL look like.. you should be able to Run a Query after the Insert based on a Key such as Date or Row / Record NO

Comment: @DJKRAZE SQL has nothing to do with it although it is attached to RowUpdatedCommand that I have just added the event handler for.

Comment: Anthbs, I posted something that you can try..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem I was having was due to updating the databound ObservableCollection resulting in a refresh of the grid and the different row being selected. The second code posted by DJKRAZE would have worked but my calls to the database are Async and therefore didn't occur before the RowUpdated event finished. To solve this I overwrote the OnDataChanged method to select the NewItemRow after the data has updated.

Here is the resulting code that worked.

```
protected override void OnDataChanged(bool rebuildVisibleColumns)
{
    base.OnDataChanged(rebuildVisibleColumns);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.FocusedRowHandle = GridControl.NewItemRowHandle;
    }), null);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anthbs +1 for explaining your solution I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the grid view's FoucusedRow property to a new row object instance obtained from RowEventArgs:

```
private void MVVMFriendlyDxgTableView_RowUpdated(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.RowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.RowHandle == GridControl.NewItemRowHandle)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { viewSource.View.MoveCurrentToLast(); }));
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { gridView.FocusedRow = e.Row; }));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

if the Flickering occurs you can try this

```
   if (e.RowHandle == GridControl.NewItemRowHandle)
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MVVMFriendlyDxgTableView.FocusedRowHandle = GridControl.NewItemRowHandle;
    }), null);
```

To Sort and ObservableCollection look at this example
[Sort a Collection / ObservableCollection](http://www.jaider.net/archives/162-sort-a-observablecollection/)

Comment: This selects the last row in the grid, where the new row has been put. I tried using this and I can see the selected row flash to the last row but it still moves back to the top row.

Comment: can you try the second solution and see if that works.. There must be something else going on because the first solution works but I don't know what you have going on fully in your code vs what I have tried in my code..

Comment: Same issue :( Is there a navagation property being set after the RowUpdated event that i cant seem to find? I can send my classes for the MVVM friendy grids if that would help?

Comment: have you checked the known issues / updates what version of DXperience are you using..? here is a link for how there stuff works and the other has the bug fixes http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6358 | http://www.devexpress.com/Support/WhatsNew/DXperience/files/12.1.4.xml#autolist44

Comment: Ok I now know why this is happening, but am not sure how to fix it. The Grid is bund to a ObservableCollection when you enter the data the collection updates the database and then refreshes the local data. This will then notify the grid that the data has changed and will refresh the datagrid UI moving the selected row to the top most row

Comment: I totally forgot you're using WPF I was thinking about WinForms can you sort on that collection or make a BindingList and then Bind the data to that list.. or are you looking to do Indexing on that OberbableCollection?

Comment: I don't need to sort the list i just need to reselect the newitemrow at the top of the grid not the new items new row.

Comment: But if the items are being sorted previously on the DB end wouldn't you need to sort..? otherwise you would have to ReBind wouldn't you..?

Comment: No i just Raise the property changed event and the new data is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it by overriding the OnDataChanged method and using your second code you posted :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22158/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-anthbs)